# Display nested list like a table

Tags: html, css

There is a nested list, which looks like this:

```
Main-Title
    Title 1
        Element 1
        Element 2
        Element 3
    Title 2
        Element 4
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>Main Title
        <ul>
            <li>Title 1
                <ul>
                    <li>Element 1</li>
                    <li>Element 2</li>
                    <li>Element 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Title 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Element 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to display the list with CSS like this or do I have to change the HTML markup?

```
Main Title      Title 1     Element 1
                            Element 2
                            Element 3

                Title 2     Element 4
```

This looks more like a table with rowspan. I tried to do that with inline-flex:

**CSS**

```
li {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

But that doesn't work properly. Also there would be multiple elements like main title and so on.. the width of the 'cells' should be fixed.

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/mkc4uh9y/1/

This doesn't work for Safari.

And the list should be continued for multiple main elements. Here it will displayed to the right: https://jsfiddle.net/mkc4uh9y/4/

Answer (score 1):

yes, reset sub li display:

```
li {
  display: inline-flex;
}
li li {
  display:flex;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mkc4uh9y/2/

Comment: @user3142695 you need the `-webkit-` prefix version? `display: -webkit-flex;`

Comment: Oops... dIdn't think about that. You are right. But one more thing. If there are multiple main elements they aren't display correctly, as they are displayed next to each other (horizontally): https://jsfiddle.net/mkc4uh9y/6/

Comment: @user3142695 is this what you mean ? https://jsfiddle.net/mkc4uh9y/10/ http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QyxOee codepen uses either autoprefixer or prefixfree to generate prefix-vendor where needed, you should use this tools too ;)