# How to get adapted width for inline-table of nested lists?

Tags: html, css

This is how I'm displaying a nested list [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mkc4uh9y/8/). As you can see the 'columns' are not aligned correctly as the content has different length. The elements - as example - should be at the right border.

Is it possible to get the width of each 'column' in a relative or fixed size? The complete list should have a 100% width.

Visibly I want to get this: https://jsfiddle.net/bsrms9ax/2/

```css
ul {
  display: inline-table;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Main Title
    <ul>
      <li>Title 1
        <ul>
          <li>Element 1</li>
          <li>Element 2</li>
          <li>Element 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Title 2
        <ul>
          <li>Element 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Longer Main Title
    <ul>
      <li>Long Title 1
        <ul>
          <li>Element 1</li>
          <li>Elem 2</li>
          <li>Element 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Title 2
        <ul>
          <li>Element 4</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of the desire output?

Comment: @Pangloss: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bsrms9ax/1/ Just as a **visible** result (as this is done by a real table)

Comment: Yes it is, if pure CSS is impossible.

Comment: @user3142695 JS is probably your only solution for this. Because how this markup is nested you are trying to dynamically set widths of nodes based off other nodes that are not parents. (i.e. you want "Title 1" to line up were "Longer Main Title" ends which it would be unaware of)

Comment: @user3142695 Here is a possible solution using JS - [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mkc4uh9y/13/)

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code from [Display nested list like a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103672/display-nested-list-like-a-table) , also a post by you.

If this is not you want, i will do as much i can to modify it and make it work.

```js
// ADD SOME CODE
// www.Agary.info Agario server ;-)
// BEST LUCK IN YOUR CODE BRO
```

```css
body>ul {
  display:table;
}
li {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <!-- Added some css..-->
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">

    </head>
  
  <body>
<ul>
    <li>Main Title
        <ul>
            <li>Title 1
                <ul>
                    <li>Element 1</li>
                    <li>Element 2</li>
                    <li>Element 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Title 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Element 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    <li>
    </li> 
    <li>Main Title
        <ul>
            <li>Title 1
                <ul>
                    <li>Element 1</li>
                    <li>Element 2</li>
                    <li>Element 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Title 2
                <ul>
                    <li>Element 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
    </body>
  </html>
```

EDIT: I see that this is not what you want, but maybe will be useful for any other user. I will try to modify it :)

Comment: What do you exactly need? i don't see any problems on your example. Separate title 1 from title 2?

Comment: As you see in the posted snippet the cells have different sizes, so the table looks very muddled. Looking at the jsfiddle example in the comment you see a clean table solution. all cells are aligned to each other...